# Css absolute without covering everything

Tags: css, html

How can I make my slide take the whole width?

```css
@keyframes slider {
0% {
 left: 0;
}
25% {
 left: 0;
}
50% {
 left: -100%;
}
75% {
    left: -100%;
}
100% {
  right: -200%;
}
}
#slider {
 overflow: hidden;
}
#slider figure img {
 width: 20%;
}
#slider figure {
 position: relative;
 width: 500%;
 margin: 0;
 left: 0;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 0;
 animation: 20s slider infinite;
}
```

```html
 <div id="slider" >
 <figure>
 <img src="webagency_images/images/slider/bg1.jpg">
 <img src="webagency_images/images/slider/bg2.jpg">
 </figure>
 </div>
```

I tried with absolute, but it covers the header section, which I don't want...

If you wish you can see the website under construction [here](https://brunoc.ovh/webagency/).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. Unless I'm mistaken,  it displays the two images next to it.

I think this is the ideal size: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XjzC.jpg

Comment: @c-bruno you forgot to add `.slider figure { width: 200%; }` in your website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set your `body` to `width: 100vw;`. If you add `margin: auto`, you won't know how much you need to move the slider in order to make it the full width of the `body`(and without setting it to `position: absolute`).

I suggest you remove the margin on the body and make it full viewport width. then, you can do it like so:

- make slider full width (`width: 100%` or `width: 100vw`)
- make the `figure` twice its parent size (`width: 200%`)
- make each `img` the size of the slider (which is half the size of the `figure`) (`width: 50%`)
- change the `figure` into a **flex element with row direction and without wrap**
- make the animation work with `translate3d` instead of `left` and `right` since we use the **static** position (the default one)

You'll also need to change some of the body's child elements in order to correct for the fact its width changed:

- make `header` & `.service_content` `width: 90%;`. it should stay centered because the `body` has `display: flex; align-items: center;` set.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slider figure {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}


/* things you need to change */

body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

header,
.service_content {
  width: 90%;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider figure img {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<!-- Section Slider -->
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://brunoc.ovh/webagency/webagency_images/images/slider/bg1.jpg">
    <img src="https://brunoc.ovh/webagency/webagency_images/images/slider/bg2.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>
```